# How to connect two Bluetooth SPP devices within the same app?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, rfcomm, spp

I was wondering, does anyone know how to connect to two Bluetooth SPP devices within the same app?  I looked at the `BluetoothChat` example, however, it doesn't give any information on how to connect to two Bluetooth SPP devices.  I can't seem to find much information elsewhere either.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume we have two Bluetooth Devices B and C. To connect them we need

1. Bluetooth Sockets, one for each device.
2. Input and Output Streams to send messages.

Connection parameters: { Bluetooth Device(MAC Address), UUID }

To have multiple connections we must create these connection parameters dedicated to a connection.

Answer (score 0):

This Thread is inside my service class.
First, bind service and create a method in service class like this,
call this method and pass Bluetooth mac address. it will connect in the background. for the second device also follow the similar procedure.

```
    public synchronized void connectToDevice(String macAddress){
    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(macAddress);
    if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING){
        if (mConnectThread != null){
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
    }
    if (mConnectedThread != null){
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }
    mConnectThread = new ConnectBtThread(device);
    toast("connecting");
    mConnectThread.start();
    setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
}
```

Here i am creating Thread class to connect and run in background

```
    private class ConnectBtThread extends Thread{
    private final BluetoothSocket mSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mDevice;

    public ConnectBtThread(BluetoothDevice device){
        mDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(B_UUID));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mSocket = socket;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        try {
            mSocket.connect();
            Log.d("service","Bluetooth one running (connected)");
            SharedPreferences pre = getSharedPreferences("BT_NAME",0);
            pre.edit().putString("bluetooth_connected",mDevice.getName()).apply();
             int i = 0;
            Log.d("service","one + " +i++);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            try {
                mSocket.close();
                Log.d("service","connect thread run method ( close function)");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        connected(mSocket);

    }

    public void cancel(){

        try {
            mSocket.close();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed to connect one",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("service","connect thread cancel method");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Similar to this create one more method and thread class to keep both Bluetooth devices in the Connected state.
I followed this and its working fine for me.